# How do you change build settings in a Swift Library?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package

I know how to access and change the build settings in a Swift app. However, when I try to do the same in a Swift library, there's nothing there. Clicking on the library name at the top of the file navigator just opens the Package.swift file, and there is no .xcodeproj file.

Is it possible to control the build settings in a Swift library? If so, how?